# Auditioning IRs more conveniently (Logic users especially)

Tags: logic, convolution, workflow

Space designer... is there an easier way to audition a lot of IRs? I have some other folders, but every time i go to select IR it seems to reset me, there's not just like, arrows that i can hit, making a preset for each of these IRs to go through is not feasible and completely purpose defeating to me...

What is everyone doing to audition a bunch of IRs easily? Any suggestions? Please? I'm not opposed to using another tool, I have kontakt 4 so i could use the convo model in that, but i'd imagine space designer is way better and obviously i wouldn't have to sample everything.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

may be this video will help you, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b3B5AMaoaM ?

Comment: ilya, thank you for that deal. I know how to quickly browse through them, but what I was actually asking, is that I have a bunch of impulse responses that are not made it into presets. I didn't know if there was a way to quickly audition those inside space designer.

Comment: Hi, Dave. I know about impulse response utility, wich can be used to make your own IR's.
Look what apple talk about that:
http://help.apple.com/impulseresponseutility/mac/1.0.3/en/impulseresponseutility/usermanual/index.html#chapter=3%26section=10%26tasks=true 
This chapter is exactly about auditioning IR.